# unix awk match a string and perform delimiting

Tags: awk, sed, ksh

I'm checking the ping connectivity checks from a host and that would ssh to another jump host and will perform ping communication. I would like to print the successful packets pinged count using awk.

```
xajvtl001:/home/root #ssh -qn xckvl002"ping -w2 -c3 xcvtc012| grep packets"
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
```

Expected output value is 3 from the packet received count.

Comment: i tried ssh -qn xckvl002 "ping -w2 -c3 xcvtc012 grep "packets received" | cut -d "," -f2 | cut -d " " -f2" It doesnt provide any results on the SSH.  But i can get the result when im logging into the jumphost and run the ping  command without SSH.

Comment: please edit the question and add the full command to the question. I think you're missing a `|`, and you have some issues with quoting...

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU grep: `grep -oP '\d+(?= packets received)'`

find the digits that are followed by " packets received"

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the number of packets received:

`ssh -qn xckvl002 "ping -w2 -c3 xcvtc012 | awk '/packets transmitted,/ {print \$4}'"`

Since you are using double quotes around the remote command, the inner single quotes lose their immediate quoting meaning, and thus characters like `$` still need escaping. This is the reason for the backslash in `print \$4`.

Note that implementations of `ping` can have different output.
In my case for instance, `N packets received` is `Received = N` instead. You might want to take care in making sure the search pattern, which is enclosed in slashes in my `awk` example, correctly identify the summary line.
Also, if there is a different number of whitespace-delimited fields in your output, you might have to use a different number than 4 for the `$4` field variable.

EDIT: A solution using `sed` for those who are interested:

`ssh -qn xckvl002 "ping -w2 -c3 xcvtc012 | sed -nr 's/.*([0-9]+)\s*received,.*/\1/p'"`

Answer (score 1):

I have used below command:

```
# ping -c3 hostname|awk '/received/{print $0}'| awk -F "," '{print $2}'|sed -r "s/^\s+//g"| awk '{print $1}`
```

The output is:

```
3
```